# Styling every 3rd and 4th item

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-grid

I have an array of items that should be displayed as cards. Every 3rd and 4th item should be wider than the others (pattern: narrow - narrow - **wide** - **wide** - narrow - narrow - **wide** - **wide**... and so on). What I tried so far:

```
.card {
    &:nth-child(1n) {width: 33%;}
    &:nth-child(2n) {width: 33%;}
    &:nth-child(3n) {width: 66%;}
    &:nth-child(4n) {width: 66%;}
}
```

Of course this only works for the first 4 items. I want to be able to use this for an infinite amount of items though.
I could figure it out neither with `&:nth-child(3n)` and similar stuff.

Is it possible to solve this with a css grid?

Comment: You need to explore the following expressions `:nth-child(3n+3)` - this will select every 3rd element for example. *Want to know more?* https://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError The statement _this will select every 3rd element_ does not fully explain the selector value

Comment: @LGSon Therefore the link included to a trusted source explaining the selector value in detail and demonstrating it with a few examples.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError I wanted you to add _starting from the 3rd_ :)

Comment: @LGSon Oh - hang on. Just taking off the gloves... well now we have that part covered too :) Thank you, glad we could keep that one civil, debates are not my strong suit and I loathe using these gloves (too tight you know).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To select every 3rd and 4th item you can use `4n + 3` and `4n + 4` in `nth-child` selector.

```css
div > div {
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div > div:nth-child(4n + 3), 
div > div:nth-child(4n + 4){
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To select every 3rd and 4th item you can use `3n + 3` and `4n + 4` in nth-child selector.